# How to Retrieve 2 Values from Spinner with Retrofit2 on Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have code to call data from `JSON` to `Spinner`, and show data in `Toast` when the data is **selected**, but I want to take the second data from `JSON`, for example type I choose **"PERMIT"** it will show code **"100"** in Toast (which will be me save to `TextView`)

JSON :

```
{
    "total_results": "3",
    "value": 1,
    "status": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "GroupCode": "I",
            "Code": "100",
            "Type": "PERMIT",
            "MaxTotalReq": "0",
            "MinRequest": null
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I've tried to display "PERMIT" results from JSON

```
    leaveType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Choose " + selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

With Response

```
private void initSpinnerType(){
        RetrofitInterface api = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        Call<LeaveTypeResponse> call = api.getDataPermit();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LeaveTypeResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LeaveTypeResponse> call, Response<LeaveTypeResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<LeaveType> leaveTypeItems = response.body().getResult();
                    for (int i = 0; i < leaveTypeItems.size(); i++){
                        String Code = leaveTypeItems.get(i).getCode(); // I want to show this when Selected
                        String leaveType = leaveTypeItems.get(i).getType();
                        listSpinner.add(leaveType);
                    }
                    listSpinner.add(0, "- SELECT TYPE -");

                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listSpinner);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    leaveType.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LeaveTypeResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "CAN'T CONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

How to set variable `Code` to `OnSelectedItem`

**[EDIT]**

`String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();`

this code displays the value of the leaveType variable with the value **"PERMIT"** I need this selected displays the variable from Code with value **"100"**

Comment: you have all list of codes in spinner ?

Comment: What list of codes in spinner?

Comment: what are values in your spinner ?

Comment: Currently `Spinner` displays the value of the leaveType variable, I need the value of Spinner to display the leaveType variable as well as the value of the variable Code

Comment: so add your Code  to the Arraylist of spinner .

Comment: Yes I've tried it, but Code comes to appear in `ArrayList` I want to hide Code in `ArrayList` but when leaveType is **selected** I want to display result from leaveType Code, any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156310/discussion-between-aldan-and-sushildlh).

Comment: Store your code into another ArrayList and when you select an item on spinner retrieve code from this ArrayList by --position since your spinner has an extra "- SELECT TYPE -" value.

Comment: @ved can give me example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your response :

```
private void initSpinnerType(){
    RetrofitInterface api = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
    Call<LeaveTypeResponse> call = api.getDataPermit();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LeaveTypeResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LeaveTypeResponse> call, Response<LeaveTypeResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                List<LeaveType> leaveTypeItems = response.body().getResult();
                for (int i = 0; i < leaveTypeItems.size(); i++){
                    String Code = leaveTypeItems.get(i).getCode(); // I want to show this when Selected
                    String leaveType = leaveTypeItems.get(i).getType();
                    listSpinner.add(leaveType);
                    // Add your code into an separate ArrayList
                    listCode.add(code);
                }
                listSpinner.add(0, "- SELECT TYPE -");

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listSpinner);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                leaveType.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LeaveTypeResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "CAN'T CONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Your Listener :

```
leaveType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // position -1 because in listspinner we add an extra String at 0 index
        String selectedCode=listCode.get(--position);
        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Choose " + selectedCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer it works. But the default spinner is **("- SELECT TYPE -")** when Activity is first opened automatically **("- SELECT TYPE -")** issuing `Toast` with the contents of" 100 "should it be opened at the time of Index to 1 but when index to 0 `Toast` is open, the problem is in` String selectedCode = listCode.get (- position); `

Comment: set an condition if position is 0 then do not show Toast.

Comment: Yes it is true, but the `Code` it directly to **101**, see my `JSON POJO` above. so the `Code` **100** in Pass

Answer (score 1):

create a class that stores both code and leavetype and add it to listSpinner list

```
class Data{
    String code;
    String leaveType;
    public Data(String code,String leaveType){
       this.code=code;
this.leavetype=leavetype;
}

public String getCode(){
return code;
}
```

make change in initSpinnerType() as below

```
ArrayList<String> codeList=new ArrayList<String>();


ArrayList<String> leaveList=new ArrayList<String>();

private void initSpinnerType(){
        RetrofitInterface api = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        Call<LeaveTypeResponse> call = api.getDataPermit();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LeaveTypeResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LeaveTypeResponse> call, Response<LeaveTypeResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<LeaveType> leaveTypeItems = response.body().getResult();
codeList.clear();
leaveList.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < leaveTypeItems.size(); i++){

                    codeList.add(leaveTypeItems.get(i).getCode());
leaveList.add(leaveTypeItems.get(i).getType());
                        listSpinner.add(leaveList);
                    }
                    listSpinner.add(0, "- SELECT TYPE -");

                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listSpinner);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    leaveType.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LeaveTypeResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "CAN'T CONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

now access code thik this:

```
leaveType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
String code=codeList.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Choose " + code, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: can i get the error that you are getting with this code

Comment: got it making some change please do the same and it will surely work

Comment: It does not work, the problem is in `Class Data`. I use `JSON POJO` to get **Code** and **LeaveType**. For `Class Data` I need to create a new class or add it in 1 activity with `InitSpinnerType`?

Comment: you can also pass your`LeaveType` Pojo class instead of creating new `Data` class

Comment: you have to create an independent class Data but with new code, you don't need Data class.It works on ArrayList.

Comment: If you are using old Code then create Data in another file then I don't think getting code from list would be a issue